# Show Google Search in Address Bar in Safari v8.0 in OS Yosemit

Tags: macos, mac, bash

I'm trying to show/hide google search in Safari v8.0 in mac os "Yosemite" using bash script, I used the following command in terminal but it didn't work even after I restarted Safari, so am I doing something wrong?

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari AddressBarIncludesGoogle –boolean
```

Comment: This is similar to the other question you've just posted: The value you want to set/write is missing.

Comment: Nop, I tried the same solution but it didn't work

Comment: I think this one disappeared when the search bar & address bar were merged

Comment: The problem is, that the command is syntactically wrong. So even it the option still would exist, it will not work.

Comment: @patrix - for sure it would help if it had a value at the end, but in this case it wouldn't magic the function back into Safari ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Agreed, but "use `defaults write com.apple.Safari AddressBarIncludesGoogle true`" would currently be a correct (but not very helpful) answer to the question...

Comment: i'm lost by 'google search'.  Are you trying to change what the default search engine is? or you trying to completely remove the ability to search form the address bar?